How to decrypt files that are encrypted with ecryptfs, after deletion and recovery
I encrypted my whole home directory with ecryptfs and accidentaly deleted the whole .Private and .ecryptfs directories. I somehow managed to recover all the deleted files using PhotoRec.
I have the following file types recovered
encrypted files/ecryptfs
application/epub+zip
application/gzip
application/java-archive
application/javascript
application/json
application/octet-stream
application/pdf
application/pgp-keys
application/postscript
application/vnd.debian.binary-package
application/vnd.iccprofile
application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable
application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed
application/vnd.sqlite3
application/vnd.tcpdump.pcap
application/x-7z-compressed
application/x-archive
application/x-bzip2
application/x-executable
application/x-lz4+json
application/x-lzh-compressed
application/x-ndjson
application/x-object
application/x-ole-storage
application/x-pie-executable
application/x-rar
application/x-sharedlib
application/x-stuffit
application/x-tar
application/x-wine-extension-ini
application/x-xar
application/x-xz
application/zip
audio/flac
audio/mpeg
audio/x-m4a
audio/x-wav
font/sfnt
font/woff
image/fits
image/gif
image/jpeg
image/png
image/svg+xml
image/tiff
image/vnd.microsoft.icon
image/webp
text/calendar
text/csv
text/html
text/plain
text/troff
text/vtt
text/x-Algol68
text/x-c
text/x-c++
text/x-diff
text/x-file
text/x-fortran
text/x-makefile
text/xml
text/x-msdos-batch
text/x-perl
text/x-ruby
text/x-script.python
text/x-shellscript
text/x-tex
video/mp4
video/webm

I moved all the *.ecryptfs file types to /home/.ecryptfs/username/.Private/ directory.
Where should I move the rest of the files? I know that some files should be also kept in /home/.ecryptfs/username/.ecrypfs/.
